# Multiple load event share a same monitor

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I want to create a CMS use HTML5, when the index execute, it loads header, container and footer. I use following code to do this

```
$('#header').load("header.html");
$('#container').load("container.html");
$('#footer').load("footer.html)");
```

It works, however, I would like to bind some event handlers into no matter header,container or footer, of course, the same handler like $('a').click(...) for each a tag in header, container, and footer. And of course I can bind three success functions for each loader, but I think it's not a good way. Is there some way to check if every load event finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of ways to approach this:

### Delagation to containers

This is the simplest approach by far. Any existing or future `<a>` tags within the containers will attain the functionality of the specified click handler.

```
$(function(){
    $('#header, #container, #footer').on('click', 'a', function() {
        //...
    });

    $('#header').load("header.html");
    $('#container').load("container.html");
    $('#footer').load("footer.html");
});
```

Failure of any of the `.load()` actions will not affect the others.

### Named function

With this approach the same named function is specified as the 'complete' callback for all three `.load()` calls.

```
$(function() {
    function bindHandler() {
        $(this).find("a").on('click', function() {
            //...
        });
    }

    $('#header').load("header.html", bindHandler);
    $('#container').load("container.html", bindHandler);
    $('#footer').load("footer.html", bindHandler);
});
```

Again, failure of any of the `.load()` actions will not affect the others.

### .when(promises).done()

In this approach, `.load()` is replaced with `$.ajax`, which returns a very handy 'jqXHR' (promise) object. `.load()` can't be used in this way as it returns a standard jQuery object; it's promise object is inaccessible.

```
function load(url, selector) {
    //make ajax request and return jqXHR (promise) object
    return $.ajax(url, {
        success: function(data){
            $(selector).html(data);
        }
    });
}

$.when(
    load("header.html", '#header'),
    load("container.html", '#container'),
    load("footer.html)", '#footer')
).done(function() {
    // All three ajax requests have successfully completed
    $("#header, #container, #footer").find("a").on('click', function() {
        //...
    });
});
```

This last approach should be used only if the click handler is to be put in place when **all three** load actions are successful. Failure of any one of the `.load()` actions will completely inhibit attachment of the click handler.

Comment: Downvoters - why no comments? Have the courage of your convictions. If there's something I can learn then let me learn it.